# Vertically move several vertices while keeping their alignment

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges

Here is my current object:

[image]

I want to move the selected vertices up the Z axis, I want the vertices on the other side (i.e. top of the object, right of the picture) to stay in place, and I want the vertices in between to move accordingly with there two constraints:

1. They must keep their horizontal position (only Z displacement).
2. The general left-right edges must stay linear (no angles at a middle vertex).

I tried the following things, nothing worked:

- Moving only the selected vertices up, creating a dummy edge between the far left and the far right, moving a middle vertex up with "snap to edge" enabled. → The "snap to edge" isn't precise when moving along Z axis.
- Moving only the selected vertices up, selecting all the other top faces, and using "scale along local Z" (shortcut S, Z, Z) to size 0. → The local Z is the one for the full object, not the selected vertices normals.
- Moving only the selected vertices up, with linear proportional editing on. → The bottom vertices are closer from the selected one than some I want to move and it changes the bottom of the shape too.

How can I achieve my goal without too much pain?

## EDIT

The final general shape should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Just humor me a moment, how many vertices do you expect you have selected currently? And can you sketch the expected outcome? The word description is too difficult to envision for me.

Comment: I have 8 vertices selected: 4 on the left and 4 at the top of the image. The expected outcome, well, see my edit…

Comment: One way to approximate it could be to use proportional editing with linear falloff, but it might be a tiny bit imprecise on the last angle

Comment: Yes, I tried that already.

Comment: I think I would approach this as extruding everything up top to the maximum hieght desired. Now i would select a vertex I wanted to keep high and another I wanted low. Pressing J would create the correct diagonal. Then it would be a matter of more selections and J and deleting all faces that weren't a part of the outcome expected. J is cool for this I think.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for the shear tool, did you try that ?

Comment: @HelloHiHola My question was marked as duplicate, but some other constraint that I didn't speak about in the question (such as the height of the lower vertex must be kept) make the answers irrelevent. Your idea works, though! I'd accept it as an answer if it was possible! Thanks!